# Inheriting yield templates from super controller with iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a super controller: `ApplicationController` which yields to my regions: header/footer. When one of my configured routes attempts to yield to another region on another template, the parent controller's yieldTemplates are overridden.

Example:

```
   ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
    yieldTemplates: {
        'footer': { to: 'footer' },
        'header': {to: 'header'}
    }
});

var SignUpController = ApplicationController.extend({
    template: 'signUp'

});

Router.map(function () {


    this.route('signup', {
        path: '/sign-up',
        controller: SignUpController,
        template: 'signUp-form',
        disableProgress: true,
        yieldTemplates: {
            'personal-signup': {to: 'signup-detail'}
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea why inheritance isn't working in this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, read the answer here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/249#issuecomment-27177558

What's happening is your Router level config is overriding the RouteController prototype. In general, options override prototype properties in iron-router.

A simple solution is to create a global object with the main yields, and then extend that object on each Controller when new yields are necessary:

```
var mainYieldTemplates = {
    'footer': { to: 'footer' },
    'header': {to: 'header'}
};

ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
    yieldTemplates: mainYieldTemplates
});

var SignUpController = ApplicationController.extend({
    template: 'signUp',
    yieldTemplates: _.extend({}, mainYieldTemplates, {
            'personal-signup': {to: 'signup-detail'}
        }
    )
});

Router.map(function () {
    this.route('signup', {
        path: '/sign-up',
        controller: SignUpController,
        template: 'signUp-form',
        disableProgress: true,
    });
});
```

There is also a minor inconsistency in your code where you declare the "template" property to be "signUp" in the controller, but then in the route itself you set it to "signUp-form". This will overwrite the "template" property on the controller. You can instead create a new controller for each route with all of the route's properties instead of overwriting them.

Comment: I like this approach, with one variation and one caveat:  instead of defining a `mainYieldTemplates` global object (and there is nothing wrong with that), I thought about referring to the `SignUpController`'s `__super__` prototype in `_.extend`, but that doesn't work.  I can replace `mainYieldTemplates` with `ApplicationController.yieldTemplates`, but not `SignUpController.__super__.yieldTemplates`.  Any idea why?  Note that `SignUpController.__super__.data.call(this)` works fine in the `data` method, so I don't know why it wouldn't work in the `yieldTemplates` property.

Answer (score 2):

I got sick of using the solution in the other answer and just ended up monkeypatching `RouteController` to behave as I'd expect in this case. Works great so far.

```
(function(){
  var orig = RouteController.extend;
  RouteController.extend = function(newChild) {
    var extendedTemplates = {};
    if (!newChild.yieldTemplates) {
      newChild.yieldTemplates = {};
    }
    _.extend(extendedTemplates, this.prototype.yieldTemplates);
    _.extend(extendedTemplates, newChild.yieldTemplates);
    newChild.yieldTemplates = extendedTemplates;
    return orig.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})();
```

Throw that code somewhere before you create any RouteControllers of your own. Any further controllers extended from there will extend onto the `yieldTemplates` field of the parent.